# Insert array of object in mysql nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, node.js

I want to insert array of objects in mysql using node js 
i am aware of inserting single data edit delete and all those function, but not sure how to do this one.

This is the json which i am using to post request

What i want to achieve is i want to insert questions array in mysql table.

```
{
    "somename":"name",
    "creadtedby":"admin",
    "questions":[
        {
            "q1":"This is question one",
            "created_date":"",
            "created_by":"admin",
            "updated_date":"sd",
            "answer":[
                {
                    "a1":"answer one",
                    "weight":"10"
                },
                {
                    "a2":"answer two",
                    "weight":"20"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "q2":"This is question two",
            "answer":[
                {
                    "a1":"answer two",
                    "weight":"10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "q3":"This is question three",
            "answer":[
                {
                    "a1":"answer three",
                    "weight":"10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "q4":"This is question four",
            "answer":[
                {
                    "a1":"answer one",
                    "weight":"10"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to insert? Please elaborate a bit what you want to achieve?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Not sure what kind of library you're using, but I guess you need  to handle this yourself and map it to different tables and insert or update based on existence.

Comment: You want insert object in one column or each column is one key in object ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this stuff seamlessly, you may want to take a look at ORM for Node.js and define 1-many relationship from your above data model and question model

http://bookshelfjs.org/#one-to-many